# How to get the size of a rotated image knowing only the angle of rotation and the size of the original image using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, rotation, matlab-figure, image-rotation

I have an image **Im** of size `50x129` :

[image]

It is a part of big cercle in yellow, and a space with blue color.

---

I rotated this image **Im** using [`imrotate()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) with an angle of *-45°*, I get **ImR** :

[image]

> I would like to *compute the new size* of the image **ImR** ?

---

One way to do this is to use the function [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) of **ImR** :

```
axises = axis;
w1=axises(2)-axises(1);
h1=axises(4)-axises(3);
```

but I want to be independent from the resulting image ... I mean I would like to, knowing the size of original image and the angle of rotation, get the size of the rotated image.

---

### Update

I intend to use this code which rotate the point `A` with an angle `t` around the `Origin` point.

```
function Af = rotate(A,t,Origin)

% Definition of the rotation matrix (rotation around origin)
R=[ ...
    cosd(t) -sind(t)
    sind(t) cosd(t)
    ];

% translation
At = A - Origin;

% rotation of the points A and B
Ar = R*At;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the position of the corners of the rotated image using your rotation matrix. And put them all in a matrix as follows:

```
rotImgCorners = [
  x_topLeft   ,     y_topleft;
  x_top_right ,   y_top_right;
  %//... bottom left ...
  %//... bottom right ...
]
```

Then the size of your new image would be:

```
%// [horizontal size, vertical size] - you can switch it around if you whish
newImgSize = max(rotImgCorners, [], 1) - min(rotImgCorners, [], 1);
```

Comment: I implemented this, it gives values lower ... it is strange , it looks the right solution : UPVOTE !

Comment: @OSryx, glad it worked for you. How do you mean lower? The numbers should come out 'real' as in - not integer pixels, because you use rotation matrix to find location of corners. If you `floor`/`ceil`/`round` them, the overall difference might come out lower than it supposed to by 1 or 2 pixels. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant. the resulting value is lower by 2 pixels, I will investigate that ... and get back to you